# How to use external repo in an another repo in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have my own repo which has been written in angular 4. Now I need to use an external repo in my project. So I can do it easily through importing the external repo as a library in my project. In this case I need to build my project every time when the external repo got modified.

But as per my requirement, I need to use that external repo in my project without building it every time.

So using the external repo as a library is not a good idea as per my requirement.
Is there any other way to use it ?

Comment: If your external repo is a project itself then how you are planning to use it in another app? Are you planning to import the desired module and use it or how?

Comment: you can watch for library changes ng build my-lib --watch